# unable to link FMOD library to VS2010 project

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, fmod

I am trying to link FMOD to my project, which I did very easily in the past in Visual Studio 2008.... So I have placed the fmodex_vc.lib and the fmodex.dll file in my project directory, added them to my project's solution explorer, then created a SoundMgr.h file which includes the fmod.h file

```
#include "include\fmod\fmod.h"
```

Where fmod has been placed in the include\fmod folder and opens ok if i right click on the above code and click "Open Document"...

But if I try to write any code at all, including a simple "using namespace FMOD" it tells me that it FMOD is undeclared or unidentified.... am I missing any step?

EDIT:
What the class looks like so far is:

```
#pragma once
#include "main.h"

#include "include\fmod\fmod.hpp"
#include "include\fmod\fmod_errors.h"
#include "include\fmod\fmod.h"

class SoundMgr{

    void init();


};


    void SoundMgr::init(){
    FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);

    }
```

And the error is:

```
Error   1   error C3861: 'FSOUND_Init': identifier not found
```

And that's for any line of the sample code that I try import from this quick guide:
[GameDev FMOD quick guide](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-quick-guide-to-fmod-r2098)

I tried adding the library as an additional dependency in the Input section of the Properties/Linker and I get

```
1. fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'fmodex_vc.lib'
```

Any of these errors ring a bell?

Comment: Can you post all your errors?

Comment: it just doesn't recognise anything, for instance if I just type FMOD:: it says "Must be a class or namespace". Or for `FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);` it gives me "Expected a type specifier

Comment: It really helps if we could see the complete errors, and maybe also some [small and self-contained](http://sscce.org/) example. Besides helping us to help you, it might help you see what the problem is yourself.

Comment: I've added the error, thanks for your time, but it doesn't really contain much more info...it just appears as though it cannot access the definitions in the FMOD headers tho they can be opened perfectly when righ clicked/open file inside the project...

Comment: It's worth mentioning FSOUND_Init is an FMOD 3 only function, and you are linking with fmodex aka FMOD 4 which will cause problems.

Comment: True, the one on GameDev was a very old article, I am using the newer structure where you create System, Channel and Sound objects and use them for the playback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so I eventually fixed it by removing the Additional Dependency in the Input section of the Linker and instead adding Include and Library directories in in Configuration Properties\VC++ directories.... Most articles I found advise to use the actual full path to the FMOD installation folder, but since I want this project to be portable and self contained, i created a "lib" and "include" folder in my project and put those files in them... (used the directories "\lib" and "\include" in the project properties which I am assuming links to the project folder, have never done this before but am hoping it won't cause dependency issues if I compile this on a different machine)...

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want fmod.hpp to get the c++ features?

Answer (score 0):

you can include the headers path in C/C++ > General and library path to Linker properties and include the dll's in you project. In this case you have the files in you release/debug dir